# How do language differences develop?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, theoretical-linguistics, dialects

What are all the ways a group of people can start to pronounce or say things differently? And what are the factors that can affect those "mutations" apart from a random shift in pronunciation of the population that could randomly spread?
Surely it's a wide question so I will get by with a wide answer.

Comment: No, this is way to broad to have any possible answer. There are tens of thousands of ways that people can start to say things differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go by examples for each question so you get the idea.

**What are all the ways a group of people can start to pronounce or say things differently?**

While "All" would probably take up a few hundred pages, you could take, say:
Palatalization: palatal consonant followed by front vowels do their magic. This happens every day, this is why you pronounce nation the way you do. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change))

However, this also happens today when people speak a little faster than usual, or teenagers make things sound cool. So one day you get "gotcha". And it gets picked up by a small group. While they will still know it is underlyingly got you, their children and their children's children will not have that knowledge, for them, gotcha is a word on its own right. And this goes on and on.

Imagine this on the scale of hundreds of phonetic changes taking place within every single tiny community of speakers: family, sports-team, school...

**And what are the factors that can affect those "mutations" apart from a random shift in pronunciation of the population that could randomly spread?**

Major misunderstanding needs to be corrected here. The changes are not random. They are just about as rule governed as artificial / computer languages. The change is automatic. What is unpredictable is which change will take place among the available set of possible changes for a given phonetic constellation. See Centum vs Satem languages - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centum_and_satem_languages

What is also unpredictable is which change of the time will be adopted by many enough speakers so its influence is permanent. Fashion, power, rebellion, coolness - all a little fuzzy for linguistics.

**Surely it's a wide question so I will get by with a wide answer.**

It is. One major force of change, phonetic and language in general, is actual speech. The more frequently words appear in a person's speech, the more they get glued together. Hence, tell hem becomes tell'em. Rock and roll becomes rockenroll, and break fast become breakfast. And there comes a point when they cease to be two independent words, they become one and the powers of phonetic changes begin to work on them.

The other force I had already alluded to is the new generations of language learners. For them a mouse is a computer accessory not a rodent, google is not a number but a transitive regular verb and y'all is the plural of you.